# Call arr.forEach(console.log) TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, functional-programming

Why do I get `TypeError: Illegal invocation` when I run forEach loop with console.log method as a handler?

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(console.log);
```

Comment: Your code will work in Node, in browser you need `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log.bind(console))`

Comment: Internal implementation of `console.log` requires that `this` was an instance of `console`, which is not if you invoke it in other context like `window` in your case.